# Can't get my Zend Framework 2 project working on hosting server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework2, locale, zend-framework-routing

Currently I am developing a webshop in PHP. For this I use the Zend Framework 2.

All of my routes exist of a locale i.e. "nl_NL" or "en_EN", followed by a controller and an action www.mydomain.com/nl_NL/profile/login.  Look here for an example of a route used in my project. This one belongs to the Profile Module: http://pastebin.com/jmim47w8.

If the visitor has no account, and no Cookie is set, the locale variable will first be set to the variable retrieved from the following function:

```
locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])
```

If a cookie is set that value will be used.
On the other hand, if a user does have an account and is logged in, the variable used will be retrieved from the user's profile.

My entire script does work on a localhost. However, on the server it doesn't.
When loading the page nothing gets shown. I have checked the error logs and couldn't find anything. However, when i place /nl_NL/ or any other locale that meets the requirements of the "locale route" regex in the url manually, it does work.

My first thought was that the url_rewrite apache module was not installed or activated, but since other websites use this module as well, and they are on the same server this doesn't seem logical. Of course I did try to check wether it was enabled by running some scripts, but to no avail. Since our server is setup to not allow shell scripts to be ran, or to check wether apache modules are enabled using phpinfo() it's quite hard to make sure.

I have tried to verify that my .htaccess file is correct, but I'm pretty much a noob at .htaccess. This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

To see what my IndexController looks like look here: http://pastebin.com/AEgm3Jmk.

All in all, I would really like to know how to get a Zend FW 2 project to work on a hosting server while still using url rewrite or any other way that makes it possible to use locale variables.

If there is something missing from this post that is needed to help me further, I will be happy to post it.

Comment: What errors are you receiving and what do your routes look like? That might make it easier to find the problem. The .htaccess seems to be the default one shipped with ZF2. (I'm currently using the same settings in my .htaccess on a hosting server and everything is working fine). Also is error reporting turned on in the php.ini file? That might also help find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, everything is working fine right now.
I found the problem to be in my local.php config file. The problem was 
an error within this file, so it was actually a write error ( corrupt file ).

@Alex thanks for the help though, appreciate it.

Comment: can you clearly explain what u did here..I am facing some issue, www.project.com/public/ works but no other module is working like www.project.com/public/country (this doesn't work)

Not Found

The requested URL /public/country was not found on this server.

Comment: The only thing I did, was re-upload the config file. Somehow the file got corrupted while uploading via FTP. If this does not resolve your problem, I'm afraid this is not the solution for you.